# JavaScript constructor patterns

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, constructor

I'm looking for a sane solution to JavaScript's only-one-constructor problem. So let's say we have a class `Point` and we want to allow object creation from coordinates.

**I'm gonna ignore type-checking in all these examples.**

```
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
```

Easy. How about creating points from other points?

```
function Point(x, y) {
   if (!y /* && x instanceof Point */) {
     y = x.y;
     x = x.x;
   }
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
}
```

This turns into a nightmare quickly. So what I want is a design pattern that decouples these two constructors (or splits the one into two, rather). Objective-C has a nice pattern for this. ObjC people create objects *with* something.

```
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

Point.withPoint = function(point) {
  return new Point(point.x, point.y);
};
```

I like this a lot, so far. But now we have two different syntaxes.

```
var a = new Point(4, 2);
var b = Point.withPoint(a);
```

Alright that's easy enough, no? Just add `Point.withCoordinates`. But what about the constructor then? Hide it? I don't know. I guess this is where you come in.

---

**And here's what I've decided to go with:**

```
var Point = {
  withCoordinates: function(x, y) {
    if (typeof x == 'number' && typeof y == 'number') {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      return this;
    }
    throw TypeError('expected two numbers');
  },
  withPoint: function(point) {
    if (typeof point.x == 'number' && typeof point.y == 'number') {
      this.withCoordinates(point.x, point.y);
      return this;
    }
    throw TypeError('expected a point');
  }
};

var a = Object.create(Point).withCoordinates(0, 0);
var b = Object.create(Point).withPoint(a);
```

**Pros:**

- No boilerplate
- Descriptive syntax/API
- Scales well
- Functional
- Easy to test

**Cons:**

- Instances don't know whether they're initialized or not
- Can't just add properties to a class (compare `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`)

Notice the type-checks in `Point.withPoint`. It allows duck-typed points like click events.

```
function onClick(event) {
  var position = Object.create(Point).withPoint(event);
}
```

Also notice the lack of zero-initialization in some sort of default ctor. Points are actually a really good example for why that's not always a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like on ObjC, you can have separate "alloc" and "init" entries, for example:

```
function Point() {}

Point.prototype.withCoordinates = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    return this;
}

Point.prototype.withOffsetFromPoint = function(p, delta) {
    this.x = p.x + delta;
    this.y = p.y + delta;
    return this;
}

p = new Point().withOffsetFromPoint(
    new Point().withCoordinates(5, 6),
    10);

console.log(p) // 15, 16
```

where the dummy constructor is basically the "alloc" thing.

The same in a more modern way, without `new`:

```
Point = {
    withCoordinates: function(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        return this;
    },
    withOffsetFromPoint: function(p, delta) {
        this.x = p.x + delta;
        this.y = p.y + delta;
        return this;
    }
}

p = Object.create(Point).withOffsetFromPoint(
    Object.create(Point).withCoordinates(5, 6),
    10);

console.log(p)
```

Yet another (and perhaps the most idiomatic) option would be to make the constructor accept named arguments (via the "options" object):

```
p = new Point({ x:1, y:2 })
p = new Point({ point: someOtherPoint })
```

Comment: Didn't draw the line between `new` and ObjC's `alloc`. But yeah, this is probably about as good as it gets. I'm still hoping for a miracle though.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiation and configuration is not the responsibility of classes. You have to add a factory, builder, DI container etc... to do the job. I suggest you to read more about [creational design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern).

For example:

```
var PointProvider = function (){};
PointProvider.prototype = {
    fromCoords: function (x,y){
        return new Point(x,y);
    },
    clonePoint: function (p){
        return new Point(p.x, p.y);
    }
};

var pointProvider = new PointProvider();
var p1 = pointProvider.fromCoords(x,y);
var p2 = pointProvider.fromPoint(p1);
```

You can use multiple setters as well:

```
var Point = function (){
    if (arguments.length)
        this.setCoords.apply(this, arguments);
};
Point.prototype = {
    setCoords: function (x,y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        return this;
    },
    setCoordsFromPoint: function (p){
        this.x = p.x;
        this.y = p.y;
        return this;
    }
};

var p1 = new Point(x,y);
var p2 = new Point().setCoordsFromPoint(p1);
```

or with a facade

```
var p = function (){
    var point = new Point();
    if (arguments.length == 2)
        point.setCoords.apply(point, arguments);
    else if (arguments.length == 1)
        point.setCoordsFromPoint.apply(point, arguments);
    return point;
}

var p1 = p(x,y);
var p2 = p(p1);
```

So to summarize the argument counting, etc... belongs to a higher abstraction level.

Btw method overloading is part of other languages, for example java, so in there you could simply define 2 constructors with different type of arguments, for example:

```
class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    Point(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    Point(Point p){
        this.x = p.x;
        this.y = p.y;
    }
}
```

Sadly this feature is not part of javascript...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, maybe a silly way of doing this, but you could add a property to specify that the object is a "POINT". Then, check for this property on the constructor.

It's not ideal, but if it fits your needs...

http://jsfiddle.net/s4w2pn5a/

```
function Point(x, y) {
   this.type = "POINT";

   if (!y && x.type == "POINT") {
     y = x.y;
     x = x.x;
   }
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
}
var p1 = new Point(10, 20);
var p2 = new Point(p1);

alert(p2.x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `instanceof` pattern, but instead move the initialization of the instance variables to another function.

```
function Point (point) {
    if (point instanceof Point) {
        this.init(point.x, point.y);
    } else {
        this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}

Point.prototype.init = function (x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};
```

### Duck Typing

A better option would be to use a **duck typing pattern**, where the `Point` constructor would always accept a duck typed `Point`

```
function Point (point) {
    this.init(point.x, point.y);
}

Point.prototype.init = function (x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

var point = new Point({
    x: 1,
    y: 1
});

var point2 = new Point(point);
```

This provides for easier to read constructor calling, and allows consumers of `Point` to pass in anything with `x` and `y` keys.

[More information on duck typing from "A Drip of JavaScript".](http://designpepper.com/blog/drips/using-duck-typing-to-avoid-conditionals-in-javascript)